# Applying a history-tweaking rebase to another branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

Suppose I have a git branch `b1` and a branch `b2` which is based on it:

```
b1: c0 -> c1 -> c2
                 \
                  \
b2:                c3 -> c4
```

Now, I've performed a rebase in `b1` which changes `c1` and `c2` into c1' and `c2'`. Now, if I rebase `b2` on `b1`, it'll be as though I'm trying to get `c0 -> c1 -> c2 -> c1' -> c2' -> c3 -> c4`; while, in fact, I just want to replace `c1` with `c1'` and `c2` with `c2'`, on `b2` just like in `c1`.

How should I properly make this replacement?

Answer (score 0):

IMO the question is somehow hard to understand. I assume you want to skip all commits before c3. This can be done like this:

```
git rebase --onto b1 c3^ b2
```

Answer (score -1):

After the first rebase, here's how the tree looks:

```
b1: c0 -> c1' -> c2'
       \            
        \
b2:       c1  -> c2 -> c3 -> c4
```

And now it should be clear what to do:

1. `git checkout b2`
2. `git-rebase -i b1` to get an editor come up with the prospective actions of the rebase
3. Now replace the `pick` lines for `c1` and `c2` with `drop`.

You won't see `c1'` and `c2'` in the rebase editor, because it's assumed those are necessary to keep; it's just your branch's commits - such as they are after the first rebase.